# Why foreach loop fail with one child element in XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I get a object reference not set to an instance of an object when parsing through the foreach loop below.  It works if there is more than one child element of RecordTypeCode.  When one child element of RecordTypeCode it throws the exception.  The XML file can have RecrdTypeCode of WORKSITE and HOME.  This file only had WORKSITE.  Using Newtonsoft Json Linq.

JObject person from XML.  The error occurs on the second line of code (the if statement)

```
foreach (JToken item in person.SelectToken("MessageContent.Employee.Addresses.AddressDetail"))
{
    if (item.SelectToken("RecordTypeCode").ToString() == "WORKSITE")
    {
        address = item.SelectToken("AddressLine1").ToString();
        address = address + " " + item.SelectToken("AddressLine2").ToString();
        //address = address + " " + item.SelectToken("City").ToString();
        state = item.SelectToken("StateProvinceCode").ToString();
        zip = item.SelectToken("PostalCode").ToString();
    }
}
```

If I get the string from  person.SelectToken("MessageContent.Employee.Addresses.AddressDetail")  for the failing employee I get :

"ReferenceObjectCode": "Employees",
  "AddressType": "EmployeeAddressDetail",
  "RecordTypeCode": "WORKSITE",
  "AddressLine1": "700 Main St Ste 1100",
  "AddressLine2": null,
  "AddressLine3": null,
  "City": "Kansas City",
  "StateProvinceCode": "MO",
  "PostalCode": "64112",
  "County": "Jackson",
  "CountryCode": "US",
  "UniqueID": "ABD4AAB5-7BF0-4814-21AF-FF639BBB50E2"

Comment: You've called the `SelectToken` method at least six times without checking the return value, and any one of those calls could potentially return null and cause an exception for the following `ToString` method. It's impossible to tell where the error is without more information.  It could be a typo in your XML file, or a name mismatch in your code, etc...  I'm also not convinced that the number of child elements is a contributing factor.  At the very least, your question should indicate which line of code is throwing the error and include a sample of the relevant XML file.

Comment: @RogerN The question has been edited for more clarity.

Comment: Can you please add the code for how person is loaded?  I ask because the code and sample JSON works together when I run it, but it depends on the outer context of what you are doing.  I'm assuming you are getting a null reference at person.selectToken()

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an educated guess based on some Netwonsoft documentation I found (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm), as well as a very useful correcting comment by Brian Rodgers.

Basically, SelectToken will return a single JToken, not an enumerable you can loop through (I'm not sure how the code you posted works for multiple finds, to be honest; the posted code seems like it should always fail.)

What you want is SelectTokens, which returns a collection you can loop through.  (See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm)

Though, again, you should follow RogerN's comment (so that a missing element won't cause a crash in the future) and break it down to follow SRP.

Comment: This is incorrect.  `SelectToken` (singlular) always returns a single `JToken` (the first match).  However, that `JToken` could be either be a `JValue`, `JObject` or `JArray`, depending on what's in the JSON.  JArray can of course contain multiple values.  There is a different method `SelectTokens` (plural)  which will return an `IEnumerable<JToken>`, i.e. multiple matches.

Comment: @BrianRogers  That is correct and worked.  I changed the SelectToken to SelectTokens and it doing the job.  Thanks!

Comment: Wait, if it returns a JArray, is it possible to enumerate through all JToken?  Where I'm confused is... OP indicated that the loop *was* working if there were multiple matches - but that code posted above seems like it should *always* fail then?

Comment: @Kevin JToken implements IEnumerable itself, so if it is a JArray (or JObject) then yes, you can iterate through its children. Whether the OP's code should or shouldn't work totally depends on what the overall structure of the JSON actually is, a detail which was never provided in the question.  He only gave us the innermost snippet.